# how decrease score on TF in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

two docs: `1. "Some Important Company",2. "Some Important Company Important branch"`

since "Important" have a high docCount(many docs has Important word), so when search on "Some Important Company"

the 2nd doc get a higher score, even though 1st doc has exactlly match.

so my question is how to boost score when exactlly matched or decrease the TF score?

my query is `multi_match` for `customerName` `usedName`,but `usedName` is all  "" in   this case

Comment: What's the query you're using? You need to use a `match_phrase` query if you want to match on exact phrase (unless your index analyzer doesn't split phrases into tokens, which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the field of your document is indexed using a standard text analyzer or something of the like. I would combine a `match` query and a `match_phrase` query using a `dismax` compound query.
This would give something like that:

```
{
    "query": {
        "dis_max" : {
            "queries" : [
                { "match" : { "myField" : "Some Important Company" }},
                { "match_phrase" : { "myField" : "Some Important Company" }}
            ],
            "tie_breaker" : 0.7
        }
    }
}
```

There's no notion of "matching an exact phrase" with the `match` query. For this you need to use the `match_phrase` query. That's why you combine the two here. Using the `dis_max`, documents that match the two queries will get a boost. You can read more about dis_max and match_phrase:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html